# What are conv3, conv4, conv5 outputs of VGG16?

Tags: tensorflow, vgg-net

Some research papers mention that they used outputs of *conv3, conv4, conv5* outputs of a *VGG16* network trained on *Imagenet*

If I display the names of the layers of *VGG16* like so:

```
base_model = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(input_shape=[h, h, 3], include_top=False)
base_model.summary()
```

I get layers with different names eg.

```
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 512, 512, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 512, 512, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 512, 512, 64)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 256, 256, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 256, 256, 128)     73856     
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 256, 256, 128)     147584    
_________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 128, 128, 128)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 128, 128, 256)     295168    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 128, 128, 256)     590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 128, 128, 256)     590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 64, 64, 256)       0         
.....
```

So which layers do they mean by *conv3, conv4, conv5* ? Do they mean the 3rd, 4th, 5th convolutional layers before each pooling (since vgg16 has 5 stages)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Architecture of `VGG16` can be obtained by the code shown below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG16

model = VGG16(include_top=False, weights = 'imagenet')
print(model.summary())
```

Architecture of `VGG16` is shown below:

```
Model: "vgg16"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)         [(None, None, None, 3)]   0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 64)    1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 64)    36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, None, None, 64)    0         
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 128)   73856     
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 128)   147584    
_________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, None, None, 128)   0         
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 256)   295168    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 256)   590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 256)   590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, None, None, 256)   0         
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, None, None, 512)   0         
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, None, None, 512)   2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, None, None, 512)   0         
=================================================================
Total params: 14,714,688
Trainable params: 14,714,688
Non-trainable params: 0
```

From the above architecture, in a **General Sense**,

1. **`Conv3`** means the output of the `Layer`, **`block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)`**
2. **`Conv4`** means the output of the `Layer`, **`block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)`**
3. **`Conv5`** means the output of the `Layer`, **`block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)`**

If you feel the explanation I have provided is not correct, please share the `Research Papers` which you are referring to, and I can update the Answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. The paper is: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/9076866 and they mention the layers on the last line of page 3.